# How to autofocus some field in tree view on "add new" button?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

For example, I have this tree view in one2many field:

```xml
<tree editable="bottom" class="check_class">
    <field name="check" class="oe_edit_only" string="&#160;"/>
    <field name="description" decoration-crossed="check == True" string="Чек лист"/>
</tree>
```

When I click button "add new", in tree view appears a new line and focus go to first field. I want to autofocus second field. Is there some parameter or attribute to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute default_focus for this, as shown here:

```
<tree editable="bottom" class="check_class">
    <field name="check" class="oe_edit_only" string="&#160;"/>
    <field name="description" default_focus="1" decoration-crossed="check == True" string="Чек лист"/>
</tree>
```